# MySQL query not getting the desired result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the "afdelingen" which are 2 and the name of the "directeur" behind the "afdelingen.naam" base on his "functienaam". But I only get the "afdelingen.naam" with  the name of the "Directeur".

How do I also get the other "afdelingen.naam" in this result.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT afdelingen.naam, personeel.voornamen, personeel.tussenvoegsels, personeel.achternaam, rollen.functienaam
FROM `afdelingen` INNER JOIN
     personeel_afdeling
     ON afdelingen.id = personeel_afdeling.afdeling_id INNER JOIN 
     personeel
     ON personeel_afdeling.personeel_id = personeel.id INNER JOIN
     rollen
     ON personeel_afdeling.rol_id = rollen.id
WHERE rollen.id LIKE 1
```

[image: A quick overview of the tables that are used]

Current result: Design & Ontwikkeling | Wilhelmus Frederikus Aloisius | van | Hot naar Her | Directeur

Desired result:

- Verkoop & Administratief
- Design & Ontwikkeling | Wilhelmus Frederikus Aloisius | van
  | Hot naar Her | Directeur

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your description is a bit difficult because of the language issue.

Comment: Inner joins are exclusive; if there is no result in one of the joined tables, you won't get a row in your result. What happens if you use left joins instead?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Left joins give the same results

Answer (score 1):

Left joins as mentioned by @rickdenhaan are only part of it; you're also filtering for `rollen.id = 1`. Since the "Verkoop & Administratief" afdeling (I think that's the right singular?) does not have a Directeur, you're eliminating that row from your result set with the `WHERE` clause.

Instead of filtering with a `WHERE`, add the filter to your join condition so you only join the Directeur role. And use `LEFT JOIN`s to ensure that you join nothing if there is no Directeur instead of removing rows from your dataset without the corresponding role.